# Tkinter Entry Widget: How to constantly check for activity and delete the field if nothing is typed in a period of time

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter, time, tkinter-entry

Trying to write a little program where you type in a Tkinter Entry widget and if you don't type for 5 seconds it deletes everything.  The best I can do is have it delete everything on the first key pressed after the five seconds elapses, but I can't figure out how to get it to do it without that extra key press.

```
import time
from tkinter import *


def click(key):
    global click_before_last_click, last_click
    # print(key.char)
    click_before_last_click = last_click
    last_click = time.time()
    # print(click_before_last_click)
    # print(last_click)
    delete_shit()


def disappearing_text_start():
    global click_before_last_click, last_click
    click_before_last_click = time.time()
    last_click = time.time()
    entry.delete(1.0, END)
    entry.bind("<Key>", click)


def disappearing_text_end():
    text_file = open("result.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(entry.get(1.0, END))
    text_file.close()
    entry.delete(1.0, END)


def delete_shit():
    if last_click > click_before_last_click + 5:
        print("TOO LONG")
        entry.delete(1.0, END)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    click_before_last_click = time.time()
    last_click = time.time()

    window = Tk()
    window.title("Disappearing Text")
    window.config(padx=50, pady=20, bg="#D3D3D3")

    title_label = Label(text="Disappearing Text App", fg="black", bg="#D3D3D3", font=("Courier", 24))
    title_label.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2)

    label = Label(text="Click start to begin, and end to save your text.  "
                       "If you stop typing for 5 seconds, you lose everything.",
                  bg="#D3D3D3", font=("Courier", 14))
    label.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)

    entry = Text(width=100, height=30)
    entry.grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=3)

    start_button = Button(text="Start", command=disappearing_text_start)
    start_button.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=20)

    end_button = Button(text="Save", command=disappearing_text_end)
    end_button.grid(column=2, row=4, pady=20)

    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after` to delete the characters after the time interval. Each time the user presses a key, delete the old scheduled function and then reschedule it.

Also, FWIW, you've used an index of `1.0` which is invalid. Tkinter will accept it, but an index is a string rather than a floating point number.

Let's start by writing a function that will schedule the text to be deleted in 5 seconds. It will also cancel any pending job, effectively resetting the timer to zero. It needs to accept an `event` parameter since it will be called from a key binding.

```
after_id = None
def schedule_delete(event=None):
    global after_id
    if after_id:
        window.after_cancel(after_id)
    after_id = window.after(5000, delete_shit)
```

Next, arrange for this to be called when the user clicks the "start" button. `disappearing_text_start` might look something like this:

```
def disappearing_text_start():
    schedule_delete()
    entry.delete("1.0", END)
```

You can then call this `bind` command once in the main body of of your program to have `reschedule_delete` called on every keypress:

```
entry.bind("<Any-KeyPress>", reschedule_delete)
```

Finally, we need to cancel any pending job when the user clicks the "stop" button:

```
def disappearing_text_end():
    global after_id
    if after_id:
        window.after_cancel(after_id)
        after_id = None
    ... the rest of your code here ...
```

---

Here's a complete working example:

```
from tkinter import *


def click(key):
    schedule_delete()

def disappearing_text_start():
    schedule_delete()
    entry.delete("1.0", END)

def schedule_delete(event=None):
    global after_id
    if after_id:
        window.after_cancel(after_id)
    after_id = window.after(5000, delete_shit)

def disappearing_text_end():
    global after_id
    if after_id:
        window.after_cancel(after_id)
        after_id = None

    text_file = open("result.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(entry.get(1.0, END))
    text_file.close()
    entry.delete("1.0", END)

def delete_shit():
    entry.delete("1.0", END)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # this is used to keep track of the scheduled function call
    after_id = None

    window = Tk()
    window.title("Disappearing Text")
    window.config(padx=50, pady=20, bg="#D3D3D3")

    title_label = Label(text="Disappearing Text App", fg="black", bg="#D3D3D3", font=("Courier", 24))
    title_label.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2)

    label = Label(text="Click start to begin, and end to save your text.  "
                       "If you stop typing for 5 seconds, you lose everything.",
                  bg="#D3D3D3", font=("Courier", 14))
    label.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)

    entry = Text(width=100, height=30)
    entry.grid(column=1, columnspan=2, row=3)

    start_button = Button(text="Start", command=disappearing_text_start)
    start_button.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=20)

    end_button = Button(text="Save", command=disappearing_text_end)
    end_button.grid(column=2, row=4, pady=20)

    entry.bind("<Any-KeyPress>", schedule_delete)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: line 18, in disappearing_text_end
    if after_id:
       ^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'after_id' where it is not associated with a value

Comment: @toyotaSupra: thanks for catching that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Wow!  I really appreciate the answer!  You're a great teacher!